# storing an answer as a print statement to be used later in a print statement

Tags: python

trying to make Python store a user´s answer to a question and then print it out in a statement later.

```
print('Today, we are going to make our own story')
question1=input('First, whats the setting going to be?  1.A farm 2.A town 3.A city.  Please make your answer 1,2,3 or else we get no story!)
```

I would like the user to input the choices 1,2,3,etc. and then keep that answer saved (along with the other similar questions that will be asked) and then have their selected answers be inputted  into a pre-edited word template

Comment: The answer will be saved in `question1`.

Comment: Have you seen the docs on [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) That's what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print('Today, we are going to make our own story')
question1=int(input('First, whats the setting going to be?  1.A farm 2.A town 3.A city.  Please make your answer 1,2,3 or else we get no story!'))

if question1 == 1:
  question1 = "A farm"
elif question1 == 2:
  question1 = "A town"
elif question1 == 3:
  question1 = "A city"
```

Comment: I want the user just to input 1, 2 or 3 and then later on the storyboard will print ¨city¨, ¨farm¨, ¨town¨ based on the numerical input they originally gave....If I just have them input 1,2, or 3 right now I get a 1, 2 or 3 in the final storyboard where the word farm town, city would be.

Comment: I've edited the answer for you.

Comment: Here is the solution I found that worked (sort of based on yours)                                     
 ```                                                                                                                                     if question1  in ['1']:
  question1 = "A farm"
elif question1 in ['2']:
  question1 = "A town"
elif question1 in ['3']:
  question1 = "A city"     ```